# How can I keep my database updating itself while no one is online (firebase)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, backend

Imagine a browser game that users have their resources to build an army/walls etc., and those resources should be updated based on their buildings even when they're offline. How can I update this data when they're off (I'm using Firebase)?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, what you are describing is an separated server other than firebase were all game logic is executed, which would make this task easier.

Comment: Or store last update time and run your calcs and updates as needed

Comment: @charlietfl it sort of works to update data based on time but it still requires some sort of human action such as logging in, i want data to be updated all the time :|

Comment: Doesn't require human interaction...your code simply checks last update and does update as needed

Comment: @charlietfl got it now after reading the Johny Bravo's answer too. You probably are mentioning the same thing. Ty ^^

Answer (score 1):

Consider Firebase as strictly a storage medium - not a service which is running all the time.

That being said, have your app "calculate" the state changes which would have theoretically transpired while the user was "offline" when the user connects.

Besides, if you did have your app continually update the Firebase backend while the user was offline, you would likely incur some surprising costs: [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better way - I havent used Firebase for a while, but simplest way could be just as in Javascript - check the current day and calculate needed changes accordingly when some user access some resource. Say UserA builds an army and it reaches 100% in 10 days, so if UserB attacks UserA army after 5 days, just calculate UserA army strength and update its database. Maybe its even more efficient than doing some background jobs - do it when its needed and server will cost less.